# How does the stage size work for Android?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I currently have one game in Flash for PC and it's 640x480 and now I want to make it for android, so which size should I make it, or should I keep it the same?

Comment: I've explained what worked for me so far here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542496/scaling-for-android-devices-with-starling-causing-some-layout-issues/22685758#22685758
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you tell me maybe, how do I turn the screen landscape? My game would be better if I made it like that because my current resolution is 640x480 :)

Comment: Just set the size to biggerXsmaller (rotated). If you want the screen to rotate depending on device position - check out `aspectRatio` and `autoOrients` properties in your app xml file.
Also this site can help you how to set up your properties: http://screensiz.es/phone

Comment: but is it a problem that my game is 640x480? Default size is 480x800 so rotated it's 800x480, that is wider than my game :\

Answer (score 0):

Stage size works ok. There is big amount of devices with different screen sizes, and you as a developer should adapt and create flexible product. Under flexible I mean your application can be aware of most screen sizes, and process them gracefully. It's part of game design, how to implement game that will fits different aspect ratios and screen sizes. For example, It's ok to restrict game for landscape or portrait orientation only. Also as independent developer you could [restrict your application for some screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

If we talk about AS3, most helpful for you will be Stage object (`stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight`) and [resize events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#event%3aresize).

Comment: Sorry to say it, but this is not an answer. @Luka - read the link I've posted to the other thread. And keep in mind to always use fullStageWidth and fullStageHeight - they are more accurate than simple stageWidth.